# Show/Hide Field Based on Value of Selection in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using the rails_admin gem to provide some UI for managing data in my application.  I have an edit form for a model, and I want to be able to show or hide form fields in the edit screen, to gather additional information based on the selection of a 'type' within the form.  I can't find an example that does this with rails_admin, is this possible?

```
config.model 'MediaObject' do
    edit do   
     field :title
     field :type, :belongs_to_association
     field :asset, :carrierwave
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of a way to do this that involves instantly showing the relevant fields when you select the `:type`. **If you don't mind saving the object first**, you could do the following:

```
field :field_name do
  visible do
    bindings[:object].type == # Put your type here
  end
end
```

This makes `:field_name` visible only if the type is relevant **after** you've already saved the object. Additionally, you could do two things to make this workaround a bit cleaner.

First, make the `:type` read-only after the object has been created. Put this after your edit block:

```
update do
  configure :type do
    readonly true
  end
end
```

Second, make all fields that are specific to your  `:type` selection not visible before the object has been created. Put this after your edit block:

```
create do
  configure :field_name do
    visible false
  end

  # you could also do this for multiple fields
  include_fields :field_name1, :field_name2, :field_name3 do
    visible false
  end
end
```

While this isn't ideal, I've done things similar to this and I don't mind it. I hope this helps.

Comment: a lot of this answer helps, but the idea that you have to persist your object part way through creation then update makes this larely unfeasible.

Comment: I agree. That was the simply the closest thing to a workaround I could find.

Comment: @MikeK. did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: no, I ended up doing something else to work around it.  On other projects I used activeadmin which I found to be more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you do for rails_admin

1. Add the following to your model (assuming you are defining rails_admin in your models):

   ```
   edit do
     field :my_field_1
     field :my_field_2
     field "load_js", :hidden do
       def render
         bindings[:view].render partial: "load_js"
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Create the file you will render in "apps/views/rails_admin/main/_load_js.html.erb" or haml if you prefer.
3. Add your javascript addition to the above file:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       //whatever you would like to do to the form here
     });
   </script>
   ```